# Setting Product Page Layout in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Months ago, I've already asked a question similar to this and I've found the same question in multiple threads with the same solutions posted which does not work for me at all.

Basically, my problem is I have thousands of products and will probably add more so setting the same page layout for each product whenever adding a new one is pretty tedious. I am using 2columns-left as the template for the product page but I have to set this every time I create a new product. I've tried modifying catalog.xml and changing this line:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
```

to:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
```

but this isn't working. I've cleared cache, reindex data, deleted cache in var/cache. I've also set the Apply to Products setting under Manage Categories to no and I've also tried creating a local.xml file and adding that piece of code. I even tried restarting the server but this just doesn't work. So my question is, why isn't this working and how can I fix this?

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 if that means anything. If possible I'd like to keep my hands away from the core files so please advice.

Comment: You have to use handle for this. In your local.xml try the below code to change the product view page layout to 2 column left

``<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>``

Comment: I've already tried doing that but it did not work at all. perhaps I've placed the local.xml in the wrong place? I've added it in /app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/layout/

Comment: It should be app/design/frontend/default/default(or your package)/layout/

Comment: Then I've got it in the right place but that did not work at all so I'm just really confused now why none of this suggested solutions are working for me.

Comment: First you need to check if your local.xml working or not. Try removing some blocks from left or right and see if its working

Comment: Well strangely, everything started working fine when I came back this morning without me changing anything at all. I don't know what exactly happened but yeah. Thanks for the time.